# Is the Shift part of the FourLands or another dimension?

Tags: castle-2004

In Steph Swainstons *Castle* series when Jant OD's and is transported to the Shift it seems like he is in another dimension but in book 2 a character from the Shift appears and helps Jant while at sea. Does this mean the 2 worlds are linked or is Jant in a semi-permanent state of hallucination?

The rest of the Circle can feel when he enters the Shift and there is the other dimension the Bugs come from so it is possible but I don't recall it being confirmed?

Comment: Does anyone know what I'm talking about?

Comment: @Edlothiad, surely this is up your street??

Comment: why up my street? I’ve never rest the Castle series, I just used wiki to clarify a couple of things.

Comment: Just thought if you were a LoTR nut you'd enjoy this series, obviously I've offended you

Comment: No not at all, I just wasn't aware of the series until you posted about it. I don't have much time for reading anymore, so unfortunately I specialise in only one field. It sounds interesting though.

Comment: Think there are 4 books now, done the 1st two and not on audible yet. If you get the time although they can be a little dark at times.